We are facing an issue where the app crashes when minimized during livestream
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.app.buildyourownfanbase.helper.CallNotificationService1@76527d with Intent { cmp=com.app.buildyourownfanbase/.helper.CallNotificationService1 }: java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type microphone callerApp=ProcessRecord{ebefb57 27259:com.app.buildyourownfanbase/u0a752} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD, android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_MEDIA_OUTPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_TUNER_AUDIO_INPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION_OUTPUT, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO]  and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:5286)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2531)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type microphone callerApp=ProcessRecord{ebefb57 27259:com.app.buildyourownfanbase/u0a752} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD, android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_MEDIA_OUTPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_TUNER_AUDIO_INPUT, android.permission.CAPTURE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION_OUTPUT, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO]  and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3069)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:7234)
at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:862)
at com.app.buildyourownfanbase.helper.CallNotificationService1.setCallNotification(CallNotificationService1.java:122)
at com.app.buildyourownfanbase.helper.CallNotificationService1.onStartCommand(CallNotificationService1.java:46)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:5268)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2531) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.validateForegroundServiceType(ActiveServices.java:2741)
at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.setServiceForegroundInnerLocked(ActiveServices.java:2452)
at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.setServiceForegroundLocked(ActiveServices.java:1797)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.setServiceForeground(ActivityManagerService.java:15948)
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$setServiceForeground$(IActivityManager.java:11974)
I expected the service to start without issues and handle the microphone-related functionality.
AndroidManifest.xml
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_MEDIA_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_TUNER_AUDIO_INPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION_OUTPUT" />
 <service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".helper.CallNotificationService1"
            android:exported="true"
            android:foregroundServiceType="camera|microphone"

            android:permission="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ACTION_ACCEPT"/>
                <action android:name="ACTION_REJECT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

CallNotificationService1.java
 private static final String TAG = CallNotificationService1.class.getSimpleName();


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service Started");
        setCallNotification(this);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service Destroyed");


    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTaskRemoved");
        //stopStream1();
        Intent intent = new Intent("GPSLocationUpdates");
        intent.putExtra("Status", "App_kill");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

        stopForeground(false);
        stopSelf();

     
    }
private void setCallNotification(Context context) {
        String appName = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, VideoCallActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("notification", "true");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        int intents;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            intents = PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE;
        } else {
            intents = PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE;
        }
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, intents);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, VideoCallActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("_ACTION_", "endcall");
        intent2.setAction("End Call");
        intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        PendingIntent endIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, intents);

        String channelId = context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id);
        CharSequence channelName = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

        NotificationManager mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
            mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId);
 Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE){
          Log.d(TAG, "setCallNotification11111111111111111111: ");
startForeground(128,notification,ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE);
      }
       else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            startForeground(1000, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE | ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_CAMERA /*| ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_SPECIAL_USE*/);
        } else {
            startForeground(1000, notification);
        }}


I'd say there's a connection between "app crashes when minimized" and "the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission", so you are possibly using a permission that won't work with the app minimized.

First, since you're also using camera in the foreground service, make sure that you also request any of the permissions in this list:[android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.SYSTEM_CAMERA]
If that doesn't fix the app crash, try adding an if-condition to check if all required permissions have been granted before starting the foreground service, for example:
if (hasAllRequiredPermissions()) {
    startForegroundService(Intent(this, CallNotificationService1::class.java))
} else {
    // Request permissions or show error to user
}

